# i cant apply compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0" into my build.gradle file

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to implement google cloud messaging with firebase. but when I applied dependency its showing error

[This is my build.gradle in android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZ31X.png)

Comment: Post your gradle error

Comment: failed to resolve : com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0
-> this is what am getting

Comment: Did you update the SDK Manager?

Comment: its working fine after sdk update. thankx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was also facing issue, but then i updated my sdk and the things started working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the latest version of **'Google Play services'** and **'Google Repository'** installed while using **Firebase**.

Please follow below steps to update:

1. Open Android studio
2. Go to the Menu bar > Tools > Android > SDK Manager
3. Click on Tab > SDK Tools
4. Check and install **'Google Play Services'** and **'Google Repository'**
5. Click on Apply and wait for the download

Finally, **Sync** and **build** your project again.